# Browser's Email field vulnerability

Tags: html, forms

I noticed how browsers autofill your email adress into forms' Email fields even if you have to start typing the email. Isn't that a vulnerability?

A website can get my email address just because I opened an url (The site have just to read fields' content via Javascript and send it somewhere using AJAX).

Tested on Chrome and Firefox with HTML5 forms and Javascript enabled.

Here is a fresh test site I just uploaded on Altervista, as you see even if I never logged in that site but I can see my email already entered:

[image: my email pre-entered]

Comment: This belongs to [security.se] instead.

Comment: This is an exploit website owners need to understand as well as the user. https://www.hackavoid.com/news/2-why-you-should-avoid-autocomplete-on-login-forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: yes. It might be even worse with password fields or other sensitive information like your address or phone number.

For chrome e.g. there is an extra warning [in their help section](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142893?hl=en), specifically aiming at your case:

> It's important that you use Autofill only on websites you trust, as certain websites might try to capture your information in hidden or hard-to-see fields.

Edit: As already pointed out, the security risk is somehow mitigated by the fact that you have to start typing first. However, there is a certain conflict between comfort/laziness and safety (as often) and you can always disable autofill.